# Ansible vault password in group_vars not detected

Tags: hash, ansible, ansible-vault

I am trying to use ansible-vault to secure a single Windows login password. I do not want to place hte password as plain text in my windows.yml file (see below) and so I am trying to use `ansible-vault` to secure/encrypt this password.

I have this directory structure:

```
myansiblehome
- windows_manage
  - group_vars
    - windows.yml
    - vault
  - hosts
  - win_playbook.yml
```

My question is about the file `vault`. I am trying to place a Windows login password here as an encrypted variable, as per [this](https://serversforhackers.com/c/ansible-using-vault) tutorial. The variable name is `ansible_password` and the idea is that I should have a hash in the `vault` file and not the actual password in text.

My `windows.yml` file looks like this (following the guidance [here](http://www.tomsitpro.com/articles/how-to-use-ansible-on-windows,1-3479.html)):

```
ansible_user: administrator
ansible_password: "{{ vault_ansible_password }}"
ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

Now, to create the `vault` file, here are my steps:

```
cd windows_manage
ansible-vault create group_vars/vault
```

Then here are all the contents that I place into the `vault` file:

```
---
vault_ansible_password: mypassword
```

When I run this file with `ansible-playbook -i ./hosts win_playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass`, I get this error (problem A):

```
The field 'password' has an invalid value, which includes an
undefined variable. The error was: 'vault_ansible_password' is 
undefined\nexception type: <...>\nexception: 'vault_ansible_password' is 
undefined.
```

So, I tried to generate a hash instead of using text. I did this:

```
mkpasswd --method=SHA-512
# copy the resulting hash to the clipboard
ansible-vault create group_vars/vault
```

I replaced the text mypassword by this hash. I pasted the hash in the `vi` editor and saved the `vault` file. Again, I ran the playbook with `ansible-playbook -i ./hosts win_playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass`. This time I got a different error (problem B):

```
fatal: [...]: UNREACHABLE! => ..."ssl: the specified
credentials were rejected by the server", "unreachable": true}
```

To overcome this, I have to do 2 things:

1. To resolve problem A.: in `win_playbook.yml`, I need to add `vars_files: group_vars\vault`, somewhat similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43044445/4057186) StackOverflow post.
2. To resolve problem B.: I have to replace the hash in `vault` with the actual password in text (mypassword).

**Questions:**

1. Regarding A: In the tutorials I have come across for ansible vault, I do not see a particular reason why `vars_file: group_vars\vars` should be present in the main playbook file (see links 1-4 below).i.e. there is no mention of this anywhere. I thought Ansible would auto-detect the variables in the `group_vars` directory??? Is there a reason why this line is required?

   1. https://serversforhackers.com/c/ansible-using-vault
   2. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-vault-to-protect-sensitive-ansible-data-on-ubuntu-16-04

      - these guys use `group_vars/vars` (unencrypted variable file similar to my `group_vars/vars`) and `group_vars/vault` (encrypted variable file similar to my `group_vars/vault`) but they are using a role while I am not using an Ansible role
   3. https://knpuniversity.com/screencast/ansible/variable-vault
   4. https://opensource.com/article/16/12/devops-security-ansible-vault
2. Regarding B: It looks like other users (see [here](https://dantehranian.wordpress.com/2015/07/24/managing-secrets-with-ansible-vault-the-missing-guide-part-1-of-2/) are using hashes as their variables). Actually, [even the Ansible docs suggest](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module) to use `mkpasswd` to generate passwords. Maybe I am misunderstanding something. Should we not use `mkpasswd --method=SHA-512` to hash the password and then place the hash as the variable value? Is it not possible to use a hash as the value in key:value in the `vault` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`group_vars` rely on file/directory name – it should correspond to specific group name.

In you case `windows.yml` is applied to group named `windows`, but `vault` would have been applied to group named `vault`.

To overcome your issue, create directory named `windows` and place your files there (every file under `windows` directory will be applied to hosts in `windows` group in alphabetical order):

```
myansiblehome
\ windows_manage
  \ group_vars
    \ windows
      \ windows.yml
      - vault
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Checking right now...

Comment: Using the password as plain text (mypassword) worked. Thanks!

Comment: Using the password as a hash still did not work (Problem B.). Any idea about this?

Comment: Password should be stored as plaintext but inside encrypted vault.

Comment: Thanks again. Ok, no further questions.

Comment: Sorry I just have one related question: If I had `hosts: localhost connection: local` then I would be running the playbook against my local control machine and not against a remote server. In this scenario, would I need to create a `localhost` directory in `group_vars` --> `/group_vars/localhost/vault` and `/group_vars/localhost/main.yml`? Or is acceptable to use:  `/group_vars/vault` and `/group_vars/main.yml`?

Comment: If you need to apply this to every host, use special group name `all` – `group_vars/all/vault` and `/group_vars/all/main.yml`.

Comment: Thanks again! Ok, all my questions are answered!