# Unable to retrieve vault secrets in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have trouble to read the secrets from vault using the VMware dynamic inventory files.

Inventory:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.ini (using it as vmware.yml in my Ansible directory structure)
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.py

Updated few lines in the dynamic inventory script 
([vmware_inventory.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/vmware_inventory.py#L213) -#L213) to read the vars -

```
'ini_path': os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../group_vars/vmware/vmware.yml'),
```

Ansible directory structure:

```
ansible/
  inventory/
    vmware_inventory.py
  group_vars/
    all_vars.yml                 
    vmware/
     vmware.yml
     vault.yml                    
  roles/
```

I can able to ping all hosts in using - `ansible all -i vmware_inventory.py -m ping`

**Trial A:**
Encrypt the password value using `ansible-vault encrypt_string password123 --name 'password' --ask-vault-pass`. Update the vmware.yml with encrypted password .

cat vmware.yml

```
server: vcsa.lab
port: 443
username: devuser
password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          62616231653730653366633966626531383362323165643034336533356165626166313466396462
          3866363332663963366231636230646465363530666366320a346539343366663135353639646234
          65363163386136636662356534343430663133313865333731336230373437663230356361373363
          3434633132343731370a393139383464306432626638633837333030623539653462343230373562
          6433
validate_certs: False
```

Error:

> vmware_inventory.py) had an execution error: Unable to connect to ESXi server due to
>   (vim.fault.InvalidLogin) {    dynamicType = ,    dynamicProperty = (vmodl.DynamicProperty) [],    msg = 'Cannot complete login due to an incorrect
>   user name or password.',    faultCause = ,    faultMessage = (vmodl.LocalizableMessage) [] }

**Trial B: Following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980859/ansible-vault-password-in-group-vars-not-detected)**
Create ansible vault file (ansible-vault create ../group_vars/vmware/vault) and add as a plain text and read that value in the vmware.yml

cat vmware.yml

```
server: vcsa.lab
port: 443
username: dev
password: "{{ vault_password}}"
validate_certs: False
```

still fails with same error

> Cannot complete login due to an incorrect user name or password.

But I can able to run the same command with plain text without encrypting the password using vault.

Env:

```
 ansible 2.7.0
      python version = 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 22 2016, 17:23:13) [GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
```

Anyone can able to help to find where it's going wrong? really appreciate your help!

Comment: To effectively diagnose strange issues, use `ansible-playbook -vvv rest-of-your-command`. ("-v" is verbose mode, and you should add more "v" for detailed output.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I read it correctly, you are using a vaulted file in group_vars and you also have some variables defined in your inventory file. If that is the case, in ansible, inventory file vars are above group_vars in precedence and chances are that your vaulted variable gets overridden by the value in Inventory. [Here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) is a link with the correct order

Best practice is to always set variable names as unique so that you don't run into conflicting scenarios.

You could troubleshoot by using a debug task to see what is the value of that var.

```
ansible <name-of-your-target-host> -i vmware_inventory.py -m debug -a "msg={{ password }}"
```

You should run the above on target host so that group_vars/host_vars are taken into account.

Hope it helps!

Comment: D Thanks for the help. I can't see the password or any other variables.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to debug the values you have encrypted.

Below code can be used to debug.

```
    ansible-vault encrypt_string password123 --name 'password'
    New Vault Password: test
    Confirm New Vault Password: test
    --> Copy the generated string to the play as below
    ---
    - name: test
      hosts: localhost
      vars:
        password: !vault |
                  $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
                  35366238333361633133643238666132353564393838306662316139663037666664316461366437
                  6434386663373838303766643034653832636363313237300a356533396138643531353434386564
                  66643239346365656631646335613764366136643137666533393031346238633363373662623964
                  3330396530633331640a626430666335303439653330646565616131376630373932653264386363
                  3239
      tasks:
        - name: debug password
          debug:
            msg: "{{ password }}"
```

--- to execute the play

```
ansible-playbook test2.yml --vault-id password@prompt
Vault password (password): test
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I can able to decrypt the string. The issue is more like vars precedence