# Use ansible vault passwords for ask-become-pass and ssh password

Tags: ssh, ansible, passwords, sudo, ansible-vault

I would like to use ansible vault passwords for the ssh and become passwords when running ansible-playbook. This way I dont need to type them in when using the parameters --ask-become-pass or the ssh password.

**Problem:**
Every time I run my ansible-playbook command I am prompted for a ssh and become password.

My original command where I need to type the SSH and become password:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml --ask-become-pass -e ansible_python_interpreter='/usr/bin/python3' -i inventory -k --ask-vault-pass -T 40`

Command I have tried to make ansible-playbook use my vault passwords instead of my typing them in:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e ansible_python_interpreter='/usr/bin/python3' -i inventory -k -T 40 --extra-vars @group_vars/all/main.yaml`

I tried creating the directory structure from where the command is run group_vars/all/main.yaml, where main.yaml has my ansible vault passwords for "ansible_ssh_user", "ansible_ssh_pass", and "ansible_become_pass"

I even tried putting my password in the command:

`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e ansible_python_interpreter='/usr/bin/python3' -i inventory -k -T 40 --extra-vars ansible_ssh_pass=$'"MyP455word"'`

`ansible-playbook playbook.yaml -e ansible_python_interpreter='/usr/bin/python3' -i inventory -k -T 40 --extra-vars ansible_ssh_pass='MyP455word'`

Every time I run my playbook command, I keep getting prompted for a SSH pass and become pass. What am I missing here?

I have already read these two posts, both of which were not clear to me on the exact process, so neither helped:
https://serverfault.com/questions/686347/ansible-command-line-retriving-ssh-password-from-vault

[Ansible vault password in group_vars not detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980859/ansible-vault-password-in-group-vars-not-detected)

Any recommendations?

**EDIT**: Including my playbook, role, settings.yaml, and inventory file as well.

Here is my playbook:

```
- name: Enable NFS server
  hosts: nfs_server
  gather_facts: False
  become: yes
  roles:
    - { role: nfs_enable }
```

Here is the role located in roles/nfs_enable/tasks/main.yaml

```
- name: Include vars
  include_vars:
      file: ../../../settings.yaml
      name: settings

- name: Start NFS service on server
  systemd:
    state: restarted
    name: nfs-kernel-server.service
```

Here is my settings file

```
#nfs share directory
nfs_ssh_user: admin
nfs_share_dir: "/nfs-share/logs/"

ansible_become_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          55543131373731393764333932626261383765326432613239356638616234643335643438326165
          3332363366623937386635653463656537353663326139360a316436356634386135653038643238
          61313123656332663232633833366133373630396434346165336337623364383261356234653461
          3335386135553835610a303666346561376161366330353935363937663233353064653938646263
          6539
ansible_ssh_pass: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
          55543131373731393764333932626261383765326432613239356638616234643335643438326165
          3332363366623937386635653463656537353663326139360a316436356634386135653038643238
          61313123656332663232633833366133373630396434346165336337623364383261356234653461
          3335386135553835610a303666346561376161366330353935363937663233353064653938646263
          6539
```

Here is my inventory

```
[nfs_server]
10.10.10.10 ansible_ssh_user=admin ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

Comment: You're being prompted for the ssh pass because of the `-k` (short for `--ask-pass`), and at least one of your commands includes `--ask-become-pass`, which would explain the other prompt

Comment: Thanks! that fixed the ansible_ssh_pass, now it works from my config file.
However, my playbook refuses to recognize my "ansible_become_pass" I keep getting this error `{"msg": "Missing sudo password"}`. If I force the password with "--ask-become-pass" it works, but will not recognize the password from my config. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you can appreciate that with the level of detail you have provided, the burden is upon you to write up an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or _at bare mimum_ include the playbook code that you believe should be working, not just command lines since the yaml details matter a lot

Comment: @mdaniel, I have updated the post to include my playbook, role, settings.yaml, and inventory file.

Answer (score -1):

try this in your inventory

```
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=root
ansible_ssh_password = "{{ vault_ansible_ssh_password }}"

In your vault:
{
  "ansible_ssh_password": "YOUR PASSWORD"
}
```

do not use --ask the value will already be there.
use ansible-inventory --host with your vault applied to verify the variables are pulled from vault.